# How Can I Turn On enableprivateipaddress Flag For Virtual Network Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I'm following these tutorials to enable a site-to-site connection on Windows Azure. I'm trying to connect a VPN to a virtual machine so I can access it via private IP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-multi-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal#part3
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal

While creating the connection for the device to the virtual private gateway, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to update the configuration for connection
...Error:UseLocalAzureIpAddress cannot be set...virtual network 
gateway...does note have 'EnablePrivateIpAddress' flag set.
```

[image]

Also, I have tried to enable it under Virtual Private Gateway -> Configuration but there is no option for private IP.

Does anyone know how I can enable this either through the Azure portal or powershell?

Answer (score 3):

As the hint on the right of the `Use Azure Private IP Address` tab. It's only supported on **AZ SKUs**. You have to deploy the Zone-redundant VPN gateways to enable this feature.

[image]

Also, VpnGw1AZ, VpnGw2AZ, VpnGw3AZ, VpnGw4AZ, and VpnGw5AZ are the zone resilient versions of VpnGw1, VpnGw2, VpnGw3, VpnGw4, and VpnGw5.

Please note that

> Zone-redundant gateways and zonal gateways both rely on the **Azure
> public IP resource Standard SKU**. The configuration of the Azure public
> IP resource determines whether the gateway that you deploy is
> zone-redundant, or zonal. If you create a public IP resource with a
> Basic SKU, the gateway will not have any zone redundancy, and the
> gateway resources will be regional.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/about-zone-redundant-vnet-gateways

Answer (score -1):

UseLocalAzureIpAddress cannot be set for Connection '/subscriptions/a4432548-3bde-4248-bf0a-bf8f531420bc/resourceGroups/ODL-az-1015067/providers/Microsoft.Network/connections/vent-eastus' as virtual network gateway '/subscriptions/a4432548-3bde-4248-bf0a-bf8f531420bc/resourceGroups/ODL-az-1015067/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/vng1' does not have 'EnablePrivateIpAddress' flag set. Click here for details
[enter image description here][1]

disable

go to connection and disable

- Use azure private ip address - disable

if it is eabled then your lab wouldn't success!
confirm before create

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).